# What is the replacement for FilteredQueryDescriptor?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Since FilteredQueryDescriptor has been removed due to upgrades in ES, do anyone have an idea on what was the replacement to this after the ES Upgrade. Currently, I am using Nest version 5.5.0? Are there any documentation that discusses the erplacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query type has been [removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_deprecated_queries_removed).

So, as official documentation stands, use [filter option](http://%09%20The%20clause%20(query)%20must%20appear%20in%20matching%20documents.%20However%20unlike%20must%20the%20score%20of%20the%20query%20will%20be%20ignored.%20Filter%20clauses%20are%20executed%20in%20filter%20context,%20meaning%20that%20scoring%20is%20ignored%20and%20clauses%20are%20considered%20for%20caching.) in bool query instead.

```
client
    .Search<YourDocumentType>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(descriptor => descriptor
                .Filter(f => f.Term("fieldId", "term")))));
```

You can also rewrite this query using `+` operator. Please have a look into [wonderful NEST documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/bool-queries.html#unary-plus-operator).

Hope that helps.